# '>' not supported between instances of 'method-wrapper' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror

I have Python version 3.6.2 installed on Windows 7 and I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method-wrapper' and 'int'

How can i fix this?

```
# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    # function to handle an opening tag in the doc
    # this will be called when the closing ">" of the tag is reached
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        pos = self.getpos() # returns a tuple indication line and character
        print ("At line: ", pos[0], " position ", pos[1])
        if attrs. __len__ > 0:
            print ("\tAttributes: ")
            for a in attrs:
                print ("\t", a[0], "=", a[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `__len__` is not an attribute, it's a method, and you'd need to call it like this: `attrs.__len__()`. But why call dunder methods when there's a perfectly good method - `len` - which is simpler to use and requires less characters?

```
if len(attrs):
    ...
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much, especially for the simpler method :)